# Hit fetch suggested group cluster rate limit

Tags: android

I use eclipse for android development. In LogCat, I see a slew of following message:

```
Hit fetch suggested group cluster rate limit
```

Is this something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem probably comes from Facebook. I just ran into the same problem and I could find some other lines stating
com.facebook.common.errorreporting.u: Hit fetch suggested group cluster rate limit.

I have uninstalled all Facebook apps and looks that there is much more peace in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. That message was flooding my LogCat that much, even the filter wasn't able to keep marked messages for a few seconds long. After I boot facebook messenger out of the phone, that message was gone.